# Dynamically use column names from fetched data query array

Tags: php, database, foreach

I have an array with fetched data from a database query:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [dataid] => 925977
            [camp_id] => 2003001
            [cid] => 
            [userid] => ushio12
            [ip_client] => 36.74.213.75
            [register_time] => 2015-04-01 22:39:04
            [country] => Indonesia
            [game_name] => TOUCH
            [server] => SALSA
            [nominal] => Rp 100000
            [logintime] => 2015-04-01 22:39:12
        )
    //...    
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [dataid] => 929703
            [camp_id] => 2003001
            [cid] => 
            [userid] => fiqri179
            [ip_client] => 125.162.70.16
            [register_time] => 2015-04-02 23:40:23
            [country] => Indonesia
            [game_name] => TOUCH
            [server] => K-POP
            [nominal] => Rp 100000
            [logintime] => 2015-04-02 23:40:26
        )

)
```

So far, based on the array result above, I fetch the data in view manually like this:

```
<tr>
    <th>dataid</td>
    <th>camp_id</td>
    <th>cid</td>
    <th>ip_client</td>
    <th>register_time</td>
    <th>country</td>
    <th>game_name</th>
    <th>server</th>
</tr>

<?php
if(isset($result))
    {
        foreach ($result as $row)
            {
                echo "<tr>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row->dataid."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$row->camp_id."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$row->cid."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$row->ip_client."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$row->register_time."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$row->country."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$row->game_name."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$row->server."</td>";  
                echo "</tr>"; 
            }
    }
?>
```

It is because I know what info the user will search.

However, this time, I don't know what the user will search (Which columns gets returned). They may search only some specific info or whole info, so that the array result will have less or other columns that this one now.

So my question is, how to automatically generate the view based on the keys (column names) array the user try to search, so that the `<th>".$key."</th>` will be dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just cast the first stdClass in the array with index 0 to an array, that then I can grab all keys with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
<?php

    $columns = array_keys((array)$result[0]);

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($columns as $column)
        echo "<th>$column</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

?>
```

**EDIT:**

With the rows you do the same like this:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr>"; 
    foreach($columns as $column)
        echo "<td>" . $row->$column . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: Rizier, thanks. It works to find the `<th>` or the column name. May I know how to echo the $rows for each column?

Comment: The problem is we don't know the key of the column (the column name) which are exists there.

Comment: @iyal updated my answer! Just use the same as with the column names to access the value

Comment: @Rizier123 : Just a correction. `echo "<th>$column</td>"` to `echo "<th>$column</th>";`

Comment: @Gaurav wow thanks! I would never have recognized this typo :)

Comment: thank you very much. I hope this will work. I actually have not tried that. :p. Will try it soon.

Comment: @iyal Here a little demo: http://ideone.com/VM3vHE <- that you also see the output

Comment: @Rizier123 I had to modify it slightly as my column names are actually dates:  
`echo "<td>" . $row[$column] . "</td>";`